# Passing props to hook components getting undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How i can pass props in two hook components?

I have a root component that uses a `Modal`, i need to pass to my `Modal` component the props `title` and show in the component:

```
<Modal title="test" />
```

In the modal component, i'm receiving the props as a parameter:

```
const Modal = (title) => {

return (
    <h6>{title}</h6>
)
```

But i'm receiving undefined.

I also tried with {} :

```
const Modal = ({title}) => {
```

Why?

Comment: `const Modal = (props) => { console.log(props.title)`

Comment: const Modal = ({title}) => {} should work

Comment: Yes, i'm doing this way @Domino987, but in my useEffect is printing undefined:     useEffect(() => {
        console.log(props.title)
    }, []); // eslint-disable-line

Comment: I'd check your Modal import statement. Are you sure you're passing the props into the right Modal component? Otherwise the props destructuring should be working. Could you share your entire parent component code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reference the props object in the child component:

```
const Modal = (props) => {

return (
    <h6>{props.title}</h6>
)
```

Or via destructuring:

```
const Modal = ({title}) => {

return (
    <h6>{title}</h6>
)
```

Comment: i try this two ways, but both is consoling undefined

Comment: Then there is something fundamental you're probably doing wrong.. You'll need to edit your question and include ALL of your code for us.

Comment: You are right. I'm editing the wrong file. Now it's working